# ExpressJS Calling Routes within Routes

Tags: node.js, express, controller

I'm using NodeJS to build a basic website as part of a personal learning process.

So here's my issue, I've created a basic User API with CRUD functionality, here's my create user method.

```
app.route('/api/users')
    .post(function(request, response) {

        var hash = bcryptjs.hashSync(request.body.password, bcryptjs.genSaltSync(10));

        var user = new User({
            firstname: request.body.firstname,
            lastname: request.body.lastname,
            email: request.body.email,
            password: hash
        });

        user.save(function(error) {
            if(error) {
                response.send(error);
            } else {
                response.send('User Successfully Created!');
            }
        })

    });
```

Okay, so basically with this I want to create a controller to handle the login and register process, so how would I essentially use other routes i.e. /login to call these routes?

So, in theory, like this:

```
app.post('/login, function(request, response) {

    // call the api method, and pass this request to use in the POST api method
    app.call('/api/users/', request.body);

});
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You will need a library like `response` to call another route. Alternatively you can use the same handler for both routes with minor differences (like returning json or some view)

Comment: @vsevolod-goloviznin Alternatively you can use the same handler for both routes with minor differences (like returning json or some view), How exactly would I go about doing this and how would I make the output conditional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explaining my idea with some code example.

You can have this function defined:

```
function saveUser(request, response, callback) {    

   var hash = bcryptjs.hashSync(request.body.password, bcryptjs.genSaltSync(10));

    var user = new User({
        firstname: request.body.firstname,
        lastname: request.body.lastname,
        email: request.body.email,
        password: hash
    });

    user.save(function(error) {
        if(error) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    })
})
```

Then you can call it from both route handlers:

```
app.route('/api/users').function(function(req, res) {
   saveUser(req, res, function() {
      return res.json({success: true});
   });
})

app.post('/login').function(function(req, res) {
   saveUser(req, res, function() {
      return res.render("some_view");
   });
})
```

You can also use Promises to define the handler, to use `then` and `catch` if you like.